# Using Entity Framework 6 code first to call stored procedure in Oracle

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, collections, types, procedure

I am using Entity Framework 6 to fetch records from an Oracle database using a stored procedure which takes an out parameter of collection type. The stored procedure returns results of a `select` query in the out parameter of collection type. e.g.

```
procedure GetEmployees(recordset OUT employeesList)
{
    employeesList = select * from employee
}
```

How can I call the stored procedure and get results? Or is there any preferred solution?

Answer (score 2):

```
using(var context = new DatabaseContext())
{
        var param1 = new SqlParameter("@Param1", 1);
        var param2 = new SqlParameter("@Param2", 2);

        var result = context.Database
            .SqlQuery<Employee>("SP_NAME @Param1 @Param2", param1,param2)
            .ToList();
}
```

If Recordset is parameter list. You should change it separately paramters.I have never seen sending parameter list to sp.

Comment: The parameter "employeesList" in stored procedure GetEmployees(recordset OUT employeesList) is of oracle type "Table" and is not a list of parameters. Moreover, it is being used "OUT" in direction which has to be provided by .net developer in code. How can .net developer send such type of OUT parameter in call to stored procedure.